# Converting multiple shapefiles into raster using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, iterator

I want to convert multiple shape files into raster files using iteration in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS. Each time I am facing the same error, which is showing:

> Error executing function. A column was specified that does not exist.

My model is attached.

[image: This is my model]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Which iteration does it throw this error on?  What happens when you eliminate the Iterator from your model?  What are the entire messages that you see in the results window/dialog?

Comment: I think @PolyGeo is right, does the model run a few times then fail or does it fail instantly? The error would suggest that the value field in the Point to Raster tool you have chosen does not exist in one of your shapefiles?

Comment: Only first shape file of source folder is converting to raster.No all coloumns are existing. I checked that manually. problem is happening at the time of iteration.After that Iteration stops, showing error- " ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
A column was specified that does not exist.
A column was specified that does not exist.
Failed to execute (Point to Raster).
Failed at Tue Sep 12 17:00:09 2017 (Elapsed Time: 1.00 seconds)
"